# get posts by self and posts by all follows with attached user using with() or joins and order by post created_at

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a follow system setup from this tutorial.
[Creating the Twitter following model in Laravel 4](http://culttt.com/2013/06/03/creating-the-twitter-following-model-in-laravel-4/)

It works for getting follows and followers and for saving them. But I want to list all of my posts and all posts of the people I follow, along with the related user object for each one and order them all by the posts created_at column.

Rather than try to pick some code to show what I have tried, lets just say I have spent two days trying every combination of join(), leftJoin(), nested joins, where(), orWhere(), nested wheres, with(), joins and wheres nested in with() that I can think of and I just can't figure it out.

For the follows I have a pivot table with user_id and follow_id. Here are the relationships in my User model.

```
    /**
    * User following relationship
    */
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
    * User followers relationship
    */
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Twit.php model. (Actually my posts are called twits but same concept)

```
class Twit extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['twit', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

User.php model

```
class Twit extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['twit', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

I've tried talking myself through this but none of the eloquent functions seem to do what I think they should do. To be clear, here is verbally what I need to happen.

Get each twit with its user and order by twits.created_at
only where user.id = Auth::user()->id 
or where user.id is in Auth::user()->follows

Help writing this out as a raw query would work too.

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:** Deleted my own answer to save others from getting confused by it since it was way off and wasn't working 100%.

The selected answer works perfectly. Here is the selected answer by @philipbrown with added eager loading for the user and ordered by the twit created_at date

```
$twits = Twit::whereIn('user_id', function($query)
        {
            $query->select('follow_id')
                ->from('user_follows')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->with('user')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

And in the view

```
@foreach($twits as $twit)                
                <li>
                    <div class="twit-gravitar">
                        <img src="{{ getGravitar($twit->user->gravitar) }}">                         
                    </div>
                   <div class="twit">
                        <div class="twit-handle">
                            {{link_to('/twits/'.$twit->user->username, '@'.$twit->user->username) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="twit-text">{{ $twit->twit }}</div> 
                   </div>                                      
                </li>
                <hr class="twit-separator">                
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll walk through step-by-step how I would solve this problem. I find it easier to get my head around the raw query before I convert that into ORM methods, so I'll write this out as I would work through it, rather than just give you the answer.

### Writing the raw query

So first I would simply get all `twits` (I'm guessing it's `twits`?):

```
SELECT * from twits
```

Next I would refine this by only selecting the from the current user (using user_id 1 as an example):

```
SELECT * FROM twits WHERE user_id = 1
```

Next we can use an SQL subselect to find all the users that the current user follows:

```
SELECT * FROM twits WHERE user_id IN (SELECT follow_id FROM user_follows WHERE user_id = 1) OR user_id = 1
```

Now if you run that on your database and change the `user_id` you should get a stream of `twits` that you were expecting.

### Converting to Eloquent

Now that we have the raw query sorted, we can convert it to use Eloquent so you are returned an Eloquent `Collection`.

Again, first start by simply getting all `twits`:

```
$twits = Twit::all();
```

Next we need to use the `whereIn` method:

```
$twits = Twit::whereIn('user_id', array(2, 3, 4))->get();
```

But instead of passing an array of user ids, we need to pass a Closure so we can do the subselect:

```
$twitss = Twit::whereIn('user_id', function($query)
{
  $query->select('follow_id')
        ->from('user_follows')
        ->where('user_id', '1');
})->get();
```

And finally we can pass in the current user to include the current user's posts:

```
$twits = Twit::whereIn('user_id', function($query)
{
  $query->select('follow_id')
        ->from('user_follows')
        ->where('user_id', '1');
})->orWhere('user_id', '1')->get();
```

Now you should be returned a `Collection` of `twits` from the current user and all the users that the current user follows.

And finally you would just replace the `1` with `Auth::user()->id` to find the current user.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the walk through. I had done something similar at one point but wasn't doing the sub query right with raw or Eloquent. It is working perfectly now :-).